# No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

Tags: grails

In controller :

```
AssocCovList.addAssoc(3, 4)
```

In Domain :

```
package com.org.domain
class AssocCovList {
    Integer id
    Integer association_id
    Integer cov_list_id
    Date edit_date

    static belongsTo = [association : Association, cov_list : CoverageList]

    static constraints = {
        edit_date(nullable:true )
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'assoc_cov_list'
        version false
        columns {
        id column : 'ASSOC_COV_LIST_ID'
        association_id column : 'ASSOCIATION_ID'
        cov_list_id column : 'COV_LIST_ID'
        edit_date column : 'EDIT_DATE'
        }
    }


def static addAssoc(3, 4){
   def aclist = new AssocCovList(association_id:3,cov_list_id:4, edit_date:new Date())
   aclist.save()
}
```

Here is sql structure :

CREATE TABLE  `omni`.`assoc_cov_list` (
  `ASSOC_COV_LIST_ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ASSOCIATION_ID` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `COV_LIST_ID` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `EDIT_DATE` date default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ASSOC_COV_LIST_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ASSOC_COV_LIST_I2` (`ASSOCIATION_ID`,`COV_LIST_ID`),
  KEY `ASSOC_COV_LIST_FK1` (`COV_LIST_ID`),
  KEY `ASSOC_COV_LIST_FK2` (`ASSOCIATION_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9584 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

**This was returning  No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here**

Why it is returning null object?
I am able to update and delete the record(s). Not working for new record.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a minute... I think the domain class itself is not the right place to call a save() on itself !
This should be done at the controller or service level. Can you give a try to this :

In your domain class :

```
def static addAssoc(<yourargs>){
    return new AssocList(/*Whatever arguments you pass */)
}
```

In your controller :

```
AssocCovList.addAssoc(<yourargs>).save()
```

Comment: You may need to go over the basics of Groovy constructors by reading http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans

Comment: Good point ;-)
Thanks for refreshing my brain.  
Is my assumption about the nullable properties correct though ?

Comment: Hi all, The creation was not working for this domain only , i am able to create new records on other domains. Could you please go through the post again (i edited the code and error message i was getting ).

@Philippe - I tried with your eg, but same error occurs. I can also provide more code and sql schema .

thanks in advance

Comment: See my new answer for another idea... hope it's the right one although I didn't test it

Comment: thanks for the input Philippe - I just tried now, but resulting same error "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here" - 
My id is auto-increment and should create dynamically .

Comment: What version of Grails are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `AssocCovList` to have the following properties:

```
Integer id
Integer association_id
Integer cov_list_id
Date edit_date
```

And then try to create a `new AssocCovList(association_id:3)` using only the `association_id`. However, by default all properties are both **persistent** and **required**. To create a new `AssocCovList` you would need to provide also the `id`, `cov_list_id` and `edit_date`.